# How to Wget login on this website

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, wget, url, google-chrome-devtools, selenium

I am trying to wget postdata login on this website using the following command but something is missing:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data "loginId=Email%40gmail.com&password=PASSWORD&submit-btn" "https://login.aliexpress.com/"
```

What is wrong with this command?

`%40` is for the @

I am pretty sure it miss a token and a referer but whatever seem too hard to reproduce.

Is there browser plugin where you can add a list of URL and it download the page of each URL in that list?

It need to keep the cookies / session of the browser (I will login from browser)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you believe it’s possible to do what your attempting to do?

Comment: I already did few year ago for many website like this but something missing in my post-data... a token or referer? I cannot remember.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is tagged "curl", I'm assuming that a curl command is acceptable too. Doing these things by trial-and-error can be tiring, so I recommend you open the login page in Firefox, then open the developer tools, go to the Network tab, press "Persist Logs" in the Network tab, then press the login button on the page. All network accesses will appear one-by-one, and you can right-click any of them and choose Copy -> Copy as cURL. You'll get a curl command in your paste buffer that will reproduce the exact same request that was executed by Firefox. (If your curl version is a bit older, the curl commands may need to be adjusted a bit.)

Chrome has these functions too, with the only difference (in the current stable versions) that "Persist Logs" is called "Preserve log".

Comment: Thanks, I will check for cURL option. But I really would like wget to do this :\